# How to pass parent variable value to child package for reference type: External Reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a ssis project in which the master package contains many child packages. All the child package are invoked with execute package task. I need to pass the "begin date" value from master to all the child package. I know we have parameter binding option in which we can pass the variable value, It works only for project reference. But the problem here is that all the child packages have reference type as "External reference". So the parameter binding is disabled. Is there is any way we could pass the value from parent to child for reference type : "External reference". 
I'm using SQL server 2014 Datatools.

[image: Screen Shot1]

[image: Screen Shot2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure all the child packages to use parent variables.

Do the following in the child Package Control Flow :

1. Right-click the desktop and select “Package Configurations”.
2. Check “Enable package configurations”.
3. Click Add and configure it as follows:
4. Configuration type: Parent package variable.
5. Parent variable: choose the parent variable to pass to child package.
6. Click Next
7. Select Value for the child variable.  It should be the very last option in the objects column.
8. Click Next.
9. Click Finish.
10. Click Close.

Comment: In SQL 2014 datatools you do not use Package Configurations. This answer is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

This is different from what you asked but you might write the value to a table in the child package which is in turn  retrieved and verified by the parent package after each child package is run.